# SVG dominant-baseline not working in Safari

Tags: svg

I'm trying to position SVG text so that it site entirely above the y-location at which it is located. A dominant baseline of `text-after-edge` appears to be the appropriate setting for this.

This works just fine in Chrome, but with Safari `text-after-edge` renders with the text centred around the y-location.

I explored further, as seen in this codepen:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/obrreb?editors=1010

Here is the output in Chrome:

[image]

And in Safari:

[image]

As you can see a number of the dominant baseline renderings differ.

Comment: text-after-edge and text-before-edge have been [dropped from SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty) and should not be used.

Comment: @RobertLongson That note is under `alignment-baseline`, not `dominant-baseline`. Do you know that it also applies to `dominant-baseline`?

Answer (score 13):

Jakob's suggestion to use `dy` is the simplest and most reliable solution.  I would also suggest you use values defined in `em` units.

`1em` is the height of the font glyph from the bottom of the lowest descender to the top of the highest ascender or accent.

Descenders are typically around a quarter of an em. So to raise the text above the line use `dy="-0.25em"`.  Correspondingly, to hang below the line, use `dy="0.75"`. See the example below.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="200">
  <line y1="100" x2="100%" y2="100" stroke="grey"/>
  <text x="20" y="100" font="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="40">
    <tspan>Hanging</tspan>
    <tspan y="100" dy="-0.25em">Hanging</tspan>
    <tspan y="100" dy="0.75em">Hanging</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

The main advantage to using em units is that they are independent of the font size.  So you can tweak the value to suit your font exactly, and those em values will automatically work for any font size you specify.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently, and found a solution that worked in my case:

After trying the `dominant-baseline` and `baseline-shift` properties only to find out that both of them don't work in all browsers I'm aiming to support, a college pointed out to me that you can use the `dy` attribute on a `<text>` element to shift it after the glyphs have been positioned along a `<textPath>`.

Here is some pseudocode/jsx to illustrate my solution:

```
<g {...}>
  <path
    id={textPathId}
    fill="none"
    transform={…}
    d={…}
  />
  <text
    textAnchor="middle"
    fill={textFill}
    dy={shiftText}
  >
    <textPath
      xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      xlinkHref={`#${textPathId}`}
      startOffset="50%"
    >
      {text}
    </textPath>
  </text>
</g>
```

Notice that this depends on the knowledge of a `shiftText` value that has to be known or calculated independently. If this isn't given I think the only road forward is to use a combination of `dominant-baseline` and `baseline-shift` while distinguishing the browsers used.